Accessing "csv" file
I'm trying to read a "CSV" file but I'm facing severall problems. The first one is I can't only select "csv" files with the file system. I try to do it this way :
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> launcher = registerForActivityResult(new myContentRetriever(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            }
        });

launcher.launch("text/csv"); 

When I do that, "csv" files can't be selected. If I change "text/csv" by "*/*", "csv" files can be selected but the Uri returned is wrong (ex : "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:1000014662" for a file located in my download internal storage directory).
Any idea?

What makes you think that the Uri is "wrong"? Have you tried using it with ContentResolver and openInputStream() to read it in? Also, note that since you did not post the source of myContentRetriever, we do not know what your code snippet does.

It ends with "msf:...", which is not the file name of the file I chose, and trying to get a BufferInputStream from it with new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(uri.getPath())) leads to a no such file exception.

That is not how you use a Uri that you get from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, ACTION_GET_CONTENT, etc.

But how should I access to this Uri?

That is covered by the duplicates. It is also covered by my original comment ("Have you tried using it with ContentResolver and openInputStream() to read it in?"). It is also covered in the documentation. And it is covered in books like this free one of mine and this free one of mine. Call getContentResolver() on a Context, then call openInputStream() on the ContentResolver, passing in your Uri.

Can now retrieve the content of my file. Thanks for your help CommonsWare.
